# Getting '$ is not defined' when entering mobile mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

So I have Laravel project with jQuery used (without jQuery mobile). I use Google Chrome (though, I haven't checked this issue in other browsers), and when I enter mobile mode (display resizing in developer tools), javascript crashes with error '$ is not defined'. What is this and how could it be fixed?

Comment: jquery script might not be included?

Comment: It's included and it works in default screen mode